# error when i try to install vue.js in my computer (windows 10)

Tags: vue.js, installation

Below the error message:

> 1 package is looking for funding
> npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
> npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
> npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
> npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-11T20_01_58_589Z-debug-0.log

Does anyone know what can it be?

I tried to run the command prompt and powershell on windows in addition to finishing in Vs Code and I was not successful

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` in your directory?

Comment: Install how? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask